# Question based on distribution of coins in purses (with some constraints)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

> If $mn$ coins have been distributed into $m$ purses, $n$ into each
>   find:
>
> $(1)$ The chance that two specified coins will be found in the same
>   purse, and
>
> $(2)$ What the chance becomes when $r$ purses have been
>   examined and found not to contain either of the specified coins

[Source:A First Course in Probability by Tapas K. Chandra, Dipak Chatterjee,Page-76,Chapter 1](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=qThxpwa9WoYC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)

**MY ATTEMPT:**

$(1)$ Total number of ways in which $mn$ coins can be distributed in $m$ purses with $n$ coins in each is:

$$\dfrac{(mn)!}{(n!)^mm!}$$
Suppose we have distributed any $n$ coins (containing the specified $2$ coins) in any selected purse, then the probability is: $$\dfrac{\binom{mn}{n-2}\binom{m}{1}\dfrac{(mn-n)!}{(n!)^{m-1}(m-1)!}}{\dfrac{(mn)!}{(n!)^mm!}}$$
However, the answer to the first question does not match. Where am I going wrong?

Also, please give some hints for the second part of the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Well, one of the coins will certainly be in one of the $m$ purses; but who cares which.   Wheresoever that coin is, then there are $(nm{-}1)$ 'places' the other coin could be, of which $(n{-}1)$ are in the same purse as the first.   There is no need to involve factorials.

(2) Well, then we've just eliminated $~nr~$ 'places' the second coin could be, is all.